# Sendmail delay 80 secs everytime--what's causing it?

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

I'm on an ubuntu virtual server. Sendmail works through php's mail() function but it takes 80 seconds to complete every time.

I've checked the mail.log and these are the entries:

> Aug  5 14:52:36 ve sendmail[13818]: p75DpuVo013818: from=www-data, size=109, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201108051351.p75DpuVo013818@server.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
>
> Aug  5 14:53:16 ve sm-mta[13826]: p75DqarZ013826: from=, size=345, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201108051351.p75DpuVo013818@server.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
>
> Aug  5 14:53:16 ve sendmail[13818]: p75DpuVo013818: to=email-address, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), **delay=00:01:20, xdelay=00:00:40**, mailer=relay, pri=30109, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p75DqarZ013826 Message accepted for delivery)
>
> Aug  5 14:53:17 ve sm-mta[13837]: STARTTLS=client, relay=address., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES128-SHA, bits=128/128
>
> Aug  5 14:53:17 ve sm-mta[13837]: p75DqarZ013826: to=, ctladdr= (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120345, relay=server.com. [65.55.88.22], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<201108051351.p75DpuVo013818@server.com> [InternalId=17901549] Queued mail for delivery)

The delay is 00:01:20..can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that targt server probably have some spam protection.

It restricts you to send mail for example 40 seconds and accepts your email on second attempt.

That might be your "problem"

Comment: Yes your right! Works instantly for gmail/hotmail.

But how can i stop my scripts from hanging for 80secs if a user has a set up similar to the one i was testing with?

Comment: if you're sending it via PHP, you could try to send it in ajax request/open socket via php which doesn't wait for server's response

Comment: The purpose of greylisting is precisely to keep zombies and clueless scripters out. Accept that email servers can have transient errors and wait a reasonable amount of time before retrying.

Answer (score 3):

Does your server have a fully-qualified domain name?  Apparently [Sendmail injects a delay when the sending host doesn't have a FQDN](http://symbiotix.net/articles/sendmail-60-second-delay):

> - first, in /etc/hostname, change your hostname from `whatever` to a FQDN like `whatever.one-of-your-hosted-domain-names.com`
> - then, in /etc/hosts, add a host entry like:
>
>   ```
>   99.123.45.67 whatever.mysite.com
>   ```
>
> Reboot and try to send a mail to yourself again. Sendmail wil not delay at all.